# Hash 512 gives different results in Python than with PHP

Tags: php, python, hash, sha512

I'm trying to connect to the Shopwedo API in Python. https://admin.shopwedo.com/developer/.

Everything works well except the hashing.
Below, are sample scripts in PHP and in Python. The hashing of the same string returns a different final result.

**PHP CODE**

```
/** * Prepare credentials: */ 
$credentials = array(    
 'id' => 1234,     
'key' => "HelloTest",     
'timestamp' => 1554888606,    
 'salt' => 'diego' );

/** * Generate token by combining credentials: */ 
$hash_preparation = implode('', array_values($credentials));
$token = hash_hmac('sha512', $hash_preparation, '');

print($token);
```

This PHP code returns:

```
b0d45466aa68db7df247d858094f88010b7c58820538309fff
e28a42458a6ce4b6b2d48b1c5b9d40492851db075af9d86b2e
1c81c4a6960d3dfb4616bccb617a
```

**PYTHON CODE**

```
import hashlib

params={'shopid':1234,
        'apikey': "HelloTest",
        'timestamp':1554888606,
        'salt': "diego"}

tosign = "".join([str(params[i]) for i in params] )
token = hashlib.sha512(tosign.encode()).hexdigest()

print(token)
```

This Python code returns:

```
34480ef855ff09d743ff5931ff39851ee4031e470c0fddb7e7
ba6a1c9a8a5145bfbcd020c11220287f2747f28f48d77893ff
f4f8dcce82ab54e70c67f172bab9
```

Comment: I've checked the python code against an online sha512 generator and they match. Please update your question with the output from the PHP code if you add `print($hash_preparation)`

Comment: You using the `encode()` function on Your tosign string. Try `$token = hash_hmac('sha512', utf8_encode ($hash_preparation), '');`if the results are now the same.

Comment: In contrast to PHP arrays, Python dicts aren't ordered, so the order in which you `join` the values is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into Pythons [`hmac` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html) to achieve what you are looking for; Pythons function `hmac.new(...).digest()` is more closely related to PHPs `hash_hmac()` than what you tried with `hashlib.sha512()`.

Here is a simple string test to show that they return the same output:

**Python 3.6**

```
>>> import hmac
>>> hmac.new(''.encode(), 'Hello'.encode(), 'sha512').hexdigest()
'b31d977587ea18dd68bb795d1b79d59ebf8b9aff7648f4f441fc421b05cc2486efe9d5b413ea6828addbca0f60294169ae56435408e0063b5f183afb64f51a5d'
```

**PHP 7.3** (tested online http://www.writephponline.com/)

```
print(hash_hmac('sha512', 'Hello', ''));
b31d977587ea18dd68bb795d1b79d59ebf8b9aff7648f4f441fc421b05cc2486efe9d5b413ea6828addbca0f60294169ae56435408e0063b5f183afb64f51a5d

print(hash_hmac('sha512', utf8_encode('Hello'), ''));
b31d977587ea18dd68bb795d1b79d59ebf8b9aff7648f4f441fc421b05cc2486efe9d5b413ea6828addbca0f60294169ae56435408e0063b5f183afb64f51a5d
```

---

Now, as user @deceze pointed out in a comment, you need to account for the fact that Python dicts are not sorted, so you could have unpredictable order of values when iterating over the data that you want to hash/hmac.

I suggest you define a list with the desired order of the keys (or skip the dict altogether), maybe like this:

```
import hmac

params={
    'shopid': 1234,
    'apikey': "HelloTest",
    'timestamp': 1554888606,
    'salt': "diego",
}
key_list = ['shopid', 'apikey', 'timestamp', 'salt']
tosign = ''.join(str(params[k]) for k in key_list)
# '1234HelloTest1554888606diego'

token = hmac.new(''.encode(), tosign.encode(), 'sha512').hexdigest()
print(token)
# 'b0d45466aa68db7df247d858094f88010b7c58820538309fffe28a42458a6ce4b6b2d48b1c5b9d40492851db075af9d86b2e1c81c4a6960d3dfb4616bccb617a'
```

As you can see, now you get the same hash/hmac output as you got in your PHP version (see code in the question).

Answer (score -2):

I don't think your functions to make the hash are equivalent. Here is a simple test to show that, just calculating the hash of a short string.

**Python 3.6** (on my Ubuntu machine)

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha512('Hello'.encode()).hexdigest()
'3615f80c9d293ed7402687f94b22d58e529b8cc7916f8fac7fddf7fbd5af4cf777d3d795a7a00a16bf7e7f3fb9561ee9baae480da9fe7a18769e71886b03f315'
```

**Python 2.7** (tested online https://repl.it/languages/python)

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha512('Hello'.encode()).hexdigest()
'3615f80c9d293ed7402687f94b22d58e529b8cc7916f8fac7fddf7fbd5af4cf777d3d795a7a00a16bf7e7f3fb9561ee9baae480da9fe7a18769e71886b03f315'
```

**PHP 7.3** (tested online http://www.writephponline.com/)

```
print(hash_hmac('sha512', 'Hello', ''));
b31d977587ea18dd68bb795d1b79d59ebf8b9aff7648f4f441fc421b05cc2486efe9d5b413ea6828addbca0f60294169ae56435408e0063b5f183afb64f51a5d

print(hash_hmac('sha512', utf8_encode('Hello'), ''));
b31d977587ea18dd68bb795d1b79d59ebf8b9aff7648f4f441fc421b05cc2486efe9d5b413ea6828addbca0f60294169ae56435408e0063b5f183afb64f51a5d
```

As you can see, both Python versions return the same hash, but PHP is different. If my PHP code is right (I have very little knowledge about PHP), then you are not using equivalent functions.

Comment: A simple SHA hash and an HMAC are very different algorithms.

Comment: @deceze Ah, ok. After a little further reading I see now what you mean.